# Using scanf() to read an integer to use in a for-loop

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int one;
   int two;

   scanf("%d", &one);
   scanf("%d", &two);

   for(int i = one; i < two; i++){ printf("HELLO\n"); }
}
```

Why doesn't this work? How can I read an integer from stdin and use it in a for loop?

Comment: Always check the return value of `scanf` and friends. It returns the number of items assigned.

Comment: What doesn't work? What error are you seeing?

Comment: @JohnKugelman The program just stops working. I don't necessarily get an error.

Comment: It should work, assuming you do indeed type in two numbers and the second is larger than the first. (You don't check for bad input, so the program will behave badly if you enter invalid input.)

Comment: add system("pause"); at the end to see the output...

Answer (score 1):

In `C` you have to declare all the variables at the beginning of the block. You are declaring your variable `i` in `for-loop` declaration. That might be the problem.
Unless you are using c99 version of C in which case you can declare a variable inside `for-loop` declaration.
Also you need to make sure that your second number is greater than first.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple the initialization of "i" inside for loop is problem. If you can give the declaration outside of for ur program will work just fine. if not it will through the error

**Error:** **loop initial declaration used outside C99 mode**